# Go web server 404 page not found

Tags: go, webserver, webassembly

I am new to web assembly

I write a `web.go` to server `index.html` `wasm_exec.js` `main.wasm` under directory `Hello_WebAssembly`

Then I `go run web.go` in terminal

Then i go to localhost:8080 it reports `404 page not found`

I am following the instructions `https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WebAssembly`

Here is my `web.go` code

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("Hello_WebAssembly"))
    http.Handle("/", fs)

    log.Println("Listening...")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

I don't know why

Hope someone can help me out

Thanks in advance

By the way my OS is win10

Answer (score 0):

I presume your project is called `Hello_WebAssembly` and you are running the `go run` command from within the folder.

If this is the case, then your `http.Dir`invocation should be `http.Dir(".")` as you want to serve resources from your current directory (the Project).